# Bootsrap 4 Dropdown Not showing all the links in dropdown-menu

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

bootstrap 4 drop down is not showing all the links in dropdown-menu please refer image

[image]

its not showing beyond red band , is there something i missing cant figure out that

```css
.red-block{
  height: 220px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <div class="container-fluid no-padding mt-3">
      <div class="row no-gutter">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="red-block ">
             <div class="title">
                <div class="light-title text-uppercase ml-20 mr-5 pt-5 ">
                   <h4 class="text-left">our <span>Services</span></h4>
                   <hr class="light" align="left" style="width:22%;">
                 </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="dropdown ml-20">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary text-uppercase dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    State
                  </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
          </div>
        </div>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

**

So link 3 is not visible , can someone correct this ?

Comment: share you complete code, at least with that red band.

Comment: After adding bootstrap cdn, your problem doesn't occur, that's why you should post your complete html as well as css

Answer (score 0):

Can u present your full code. Anyways, please try my code and see if it helps. I have replaced your div and anchor to ul - li - anchor structure.

let me know if it helps.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="dropdown ml-20">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary text-uppercase dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
     State
   </button>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
     <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a></li>
     <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a></li>
     <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Its working in stack overflow snippet but not on my HTML file ,it get hidden due to container overflow:hidden property , tried z-index too

Comment: Please paste the full file; not just body ; from <html> to </html>; I will cross check

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in your css.

i dont know this will work inside your html file or not.

```
.dropdown-menu{
  postition: relative;
  z-index:-1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this happens when you try to display an element outside of a container/element that is `overflow: hidden`
Ex:

```
.red-block{
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: red;
  height: 220px;
}
```

What you could do is 1. Check if any there's any `overflow: hidden` element and change it or 2. move the `.dropdown` element right next to the `div.red-block` like this:

HTML

```
     <div class="container-fluid no-padding mt-3">
      <div class="row no-gutter">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <!-- RED BLOCK -->
          <div class="red-block ">
            <div class="title">
              <div class="light-title text-uppercase ml-20 mr-5 pt-5 ">
                <h4 class="text-left">our <span>Services</span></h4>
                <hr class="light" align="left" style="width:22%;">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- END RED BLOCK 
           DROPDOWN -->
          <div class="dropdown ml-20">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary text-uppercase dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                State
              </button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
<!-- END DROPDOWN -->
```

CSS

```
.red-block{
  background-color: red;
  height: 220px;
}
.dropdown.ml-20{
   position: absolute;
    bottom: 25%;
}
```

Hope it helps